# where to find the variable that contains captured image data by the camera using zxing android library?

Tags: android, zxing

I want to get the variable containing the Image data captured by the camera inside zxing android library just before it gets decoded.
I thought the Byte[] data variable(YUV Preview Frame), passed in the "decode" function in the DecodeHandler class, is the one that got what I want but apperantly I am wrong, and there is a difference between the data I am looking for and this YUV Preview Frame data, which I cannot understand.
Can any one help me in that Please!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format of preview data is NV21. The variable used to store camera data is located in **PlanarYUVLuminanceSource.java**:

```
public PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(byte[] yuvData,
                                  int dataWidth,
                                  int dataHeight,
                                  int left,
                                  int top,
                                  int width,
                                  int height,
                                  boolean reverseHorizontal) {
    super(width, height);

    if (left + width > dataWidth || top + height > dataHeight) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Crop rectangle does not fit within image data.");
    }

    this.yuvData = yuvData;
    this.dataWidth = dataWidth;
    this.dataHeight = dataHeight;
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    if (reverseHorizontal) {
      reverseHorizontal(width, height);
    }
  }
```

It's yuvData!

Comment: But this yuvData, isn't it the same "data" passed as an Argument in the "decode" Methode inside the "DecodeHandler" class:      private void decode(byte [] data, int width, int height)?

Comment: I didn't see DecodeHandler in ZXing. You can use MultiFormatReader to decode barcode image. Here is a post - [How to Write and Read QR Code with ZXing in Java](http://www.codepool.biz/zxing-write-read-qrcode.html) which introduces how to read and write barcode with ZXing.